# Finding Great circle distances from points in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, coordinates

I have the code below to calculate the distance between points on a map. My aim is to do the following:

- Have a start point and the locations from the locations dictionary,
- Loop through the dictionary and calculate the distance from all
  points to the start point.
- Find the location with the minimum distance from the start point.
- Then pair that location with the start point to form a pair of nodes
  to connect an edge.
- After doing that, make the minimum location as the new start point
  and remove it from the locations dictionary.

I will then go back to the previous step for the rest of the points.

I am currently able to get the distance from the first start point, but unable to loop through the rest of the points in the locations dictionary.

Any advice is highly appreciated.

```
from math import atan2, cos, sin, sqrt, radians

start = (43.82846160000000000000, -79.53560419999997000000)

locations = {
        'one':(43.65162010000000000000, -79.73558579999997000000),
        'two':(43.75846240000000000000, -79.22252100000003000000),
        'thr':(43.71773540000000000000, -79.74897190000002000000)
        }

cal_distances = {}

nodes = []

def dis():    

    y = len(locations)

    x = 0       

    while x != y:

        for key, value in locations.iteritems():                        
            d = calc_distance(value)
            cal_distances.setdefault(key,[])
            cal_distances[key].append(d)

        print cal_distances               

        min_distance = min(cal_distances, key = cal_distances.get)     

        if locations.has_key(min_distance):
            for ky, val in locations.iteritems():
                if ky == min_distance:
                    start = val   
            locations.pop(ky)                
        x = x+1  

    print locations

    print nodes

def calc_distance(destination):
     """great-circle distance between two points on a sphere from their longitudes and latitudes"""
    lat1, lon1 = start
    lat2, lon2 = destination
    radius     = 6371 # km. earth

    dlat = radians(lat2-lat1)
    dlon = radians(lon2-lon1) 

    a = (sin(dlat/2) * sin(dlat/2) + cos(radians(lat1)) * cos(radians(lat2)) * sin(dlon/2) * sin(dlon/2))
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))
    d = radius * c

    return d

dis()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as it stands is quite confusing. I think what you are trying to achieve is:

```
start = (43.82846160000000000000, -79.53560419999997000000)

locations = {'one':(43.65162010000000000000, -79.73558579999997000000),
             'two':(43.75846240000000000000, -79.22252100000003000000),
             'thr':(43.71773540000000000000, -79.74897190000002000000)}

def dis(start, locations):

    nodes = []       

    while locations:
    # until the dictionary of locations is empty

        nearest = min(locations, key=lambda k: calc_distance(start, locations[k]))
        # find the key of the closest location to start

        nodes.append((start, locations[nearest]))
        # add a tuple (start, closest location) to the node list

        start = locations.pop(nearest)
        # remove the closest location from locations and assign to start

    return nodes

def calc_distance(start, destination):
    # ...

nodes = dis(start, locations)
```

Note that I have made `start` an explicit argument to `calc_distance`, and `start` and `locations` explicit arguments to `dis` - wherever possible, don't rely on scope for access to variables. The output I get in `nodes` is:

```
[((43.8284616, -79.53560419999997), (43.7177354, -79.74897190000002)), 
 ((43.7177354, -79.74897190000002), (43.6516201, -79.73558579999997)), 
 ((43.6516201, -79.73558579999997), (43.7584624, -79.22252100000003))]
```

Comment: thanks for your response and apologies for my code, it was just trying all ways to make it work, will bear that in min next time :). This was what I was trying to do and it gives me what I was looking for. Highly Appreciated